# Objective C: Getting MPMediaItem 'Favorite' property

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmediaitem

I was looking at Apple's documentation, and I cannot seem to find a way to get whether or not an MPMediaItem is a 'favorite' track or not. See screenshot below, with the pink heart.

How can one get this property?  I know since it's a new feature, it's availability would be limited to iOS 8.4 or later.

[image]

Here's some code I'm using to get other properties from MPMediaItems, via the music picker:

```
- (void) processMediaItems:(MPMediaItemCollection *)mediaItemCollection
{
            //iterate through selected songs
            if (mediaItemCollection) {
                NSArray *allSelectedSongs = [mediaItemCollection items];

                for(MPMediaItem *song in allSelectedSongs)
                {
                    NSURL *songURL = [song valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];
                    NSNumber *ident = [song valueForProperty:MPMediaEntityPropertyPersistentID];
                    NSString *identString = [BukketHelper convertULLToNSString:ident];
                    NSNumber *isCloud = [song valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyIsCloudItem];
                }

 //do other stuff here
}
```

Anyone have ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use Apple Music API to get or set users's Like/Dislike to a song like this:

```
GET https://api.music.apple.com/v1/me/ratings/songs/{id}
```

From: [Apple Docs link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applemusicapi/get_personal_song_rating)

Comment: I would recommend adding more information to your answer, such as the request/response details

Comment: Well Apple Music API has a whole bunch of documents on how to build a request and analysis responses. If the asker really decides to use Apple Music API for the task, I would love to provide more information on to them, but I believe that will be another topic. There are too many things to do before request can be built.

Comment: Goodness thanks @AMGuru. I was looking for this for ages!